# inserting entities issue in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am currently trying to integrate hibernate with spring.I am using the dao design pattern and mysql as database. i am trying to add the contacte entity in the db but it's not added and no error was displayed.By the way i can get the list of contact and get it by id but i can't update or insert.

this is my context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          ">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mailmaneger" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
          <property name="packagesToScan" value="biz.picosoft.entity"/>



        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">

            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>


            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="d" class="biz.picosoft.daoImpl.ContacteDaoImpl">
        <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

this is my generic dao impl

```
package biz.picosoft.daoImpl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import dao.GenericDao;
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public class GenericDaoImp<T>  implements GenericDao<T> {
    HibernateTemplate template;

    protected Class<T> daoType;
    public GenericDaoImp() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public HibernateTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void insert(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        template.save(t);

    }

    public void update(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        template.update(t);
    }

    public void delete(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        template.delete(t);
    }

    public T findById(Class<T> t, String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return template.get(t, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return template.loadAll(daoType);
    } 




}
```

this is my entity file

```
package biz.picosoft.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table( name = "Contacte")
public class Contacte  implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "idContact")
int idContact;
 @Column(name = "nom")
String nom;
 @Column(name = "mail")
String mail;
 @Column(name = "téléphone")
String téléphone;
 @Column(name = "adresse")
String adresse;

public Contacte() {
    super();
}

public Contacte(  String nom, String mail, String téléphone, String adresse) {
    super();

    this.nom = nom;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.téléphone = téléphone;
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

public long getIdContact() {
    return idContact;
}


public void setIdContact(int idContact) {
    this.idContact = idContact;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public String getTéléphone() {
    return téléphone;
}

public void setTéléphone(String téléphone) {
    this.téléphone = téléphone;
}

public String getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}

public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (idContact ^ (idContact >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Contacte other = (Contacte) obj;
    if (idContact != other.idContact)
        return false;
    return true;
}


}
```

my contacteDaoImp file

```
package biz.picosoft.daoImpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import biz.picosoft.entity.Contacte;
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public class ContacteDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImp<Contacte> implements ContacteDao{

}
```

my main

```
package biz.picosoft.mains;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import biz.picosoft.daoImpl.ContacteDaoImpl;
import biz.picosoft.entity.Contacte;

public class TestHibernate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Contacte contacte=new Contacte("fatma", "test2",  "test",  "test");

ApplicationContext context =
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
 contacte.setIdContact (4);
ContacteDaoImpl contacteDaoImpl=(ContacteDaoImpl) context.getBean("d");
System.out.println( contacteDaoImpl.findAll().size());
contacteDaoImpl.insert(contacte);

    }

}
```

Comment: where are you invoking insert or update statement? The code in main method is just fetching all the details, where as you are creating the Contacte object but you are not invoking insert or update.

Comment: no when i change findall with insert i got nothing

Answer (score 1):

please add the following along with its namespace:

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

and in schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd


<!-- This tells Spring to activate annotation-driven transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

You can remove the (readOnly=false) because by default it is false

Reference:
http://springinpractice.com/2008/03/18/annotation-based-transactions-in-spring

Comment: nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c : Le caractère générique concordant est strict, mais aucune déclaration ne peut être trouvée pour l'élément 'tx:annotation-driven' i got this error while adding  <tx:annotation-driven/>

Comment: Did you really add `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd` to the schema location?